# Parse string based on pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am using php 5 to parse a string. My input string looks like the following:

> {Billion is|Millions are|Trillion is} {an extremely |a| a generously |
>   a very} { tiny|little |smallish |short |small} stage in a vast
>   {galactic| |large|huge|tense|big |cosmic}
>   {universe|Colosseum|planet|arena}.

Find below my minimum viable example:

```
<?php

function process($text)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\[(((?>[^\[\]]+)|(?R))*)\]/x', array(
        $this,
        'replace'
    ), $text);
}
function replace($text)
{
    $text  = $this->process($text[1]);
    $parts = explode('|', $text);
    return $parts[array_rand($parts)];
}

$text = "{Billion is|Millions are|Trillion is} {an extremely |a| a generously | a very} { tiny|little |smallish |short |small} stage in a vast {galactic| |large|huge|tense|big |cosmic} {universe|Colosseum|planet|arena}.";

$res = process($text);

echo $res;
```

As you can see I am trying to parse the following pattern f.ex.: `{Billion is|Millions are|Trillion is}` using the above regex, `/\[(((?>[^\[\]]+)|(?R))*)\]/x`.

As a result I am getting the same string as inputted. I would like to get as an output for example:

> Billion is a very little stage in a vast huge arena.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the input string.

Comment: @Rafael Please find my updated question. Furthermore, my input string is also included in the example code.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. Really interesting question though.

Answer (score 3):

How would your current code generate anything.

1. Your regex doesn't fit. It matches nested bracketed stuff and not braced. Try[`{([^}]*)}`](https://regex101.com/r/A9Qkwq/1/) for [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) everything inside `{`...`}` to `$m[1]` if there are no nested braces.
2. [Read about `preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). The second argument can not be an array.

A working code with some further adjustments could look like this:

```
function process($text) {
  return preg_replace_callback('/{([^}]*)}/', 'replace', $text);
}

function replace($m) {
  $parts = explode('|', $m[1]);
  shuffle($parts);
  return $parts[0];
}

$text = "{Billion is|Millions are|Trillion is} {an extremely|a|a generously|a very} {tiny|little|smallish|short|small} stage in a vast {galactic||large|huge|tense|big|cosmic} {universe|Colosseum|planet|arena}.";

echo process($text);
```

> Billion is a generously short stage in a vast  Colosseum.

[Here is a demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/1046847)

(you can also use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) if PHP >= 5.3)